# DateAdd function equivalent in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

What is the equivalent of DateAdd function in Acumatica?
I see there is a DateDiff but no DateAdd.

I am trying to do the following-
SQL:
(DateAdd(DAY,  (180 * RemainingQty / TotalQty), GetDate()))

[PXDBCalced(typeof(Add, totalQty>, AccessInfo.businessDate>), typeof(DateTime))]

I get an error saying "Specified cast is not valid.."

Can someone provide any guideline on how to achieve what I am trying to accomplish? Thanks.

Comment: You should just be able to use PXFormula and use the Add, Sub, etc. BqlFunctions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add days with the BQL Add class.

If day is a PXFormula DAC field, you can calculate the value like this:

```
[PXDBCalced(typeof(Add<Current<AccessInfo.businessDate>, NullableIntDACField>), typeof(DateTime))]
```

You can also use a constant:

```
public class int180 : Constant<int>
    {
        public int180()
            : base((int)180)
        {
        }
    }

[PXDBCalced(typeof(Add<Current<AccessInfo.businessDate>, int180>), typeof(DateTime))]
```

Combining both techniques for your specific formula would be:

```
[PXDBCalced(typeof(Add<Current<AccessInfo.businessDate>, Div<Mult<int180, remainingQty>, totalQty>>), typeof(DateTime))]
```

Comment: Thanks, however I'm now receiving an error as follows- The multi-part identifier "AccessInfo.BusinessDate" could not be bound. I also tried using Today but then I get an error saying - The Object doesn't implement iConvertible.      [PXDBCalced(typeof(Add<AccessInfo.businessDate, Div<Mult<int180, remainingQty>, totalQty>>), typeof(DateTime))]

Comment: For AccessInfo and similar singleton tables, you need to use the current class like this: Current<AccessInfo.businessDate>. Can you check if remainingQty and totalQty are of Int? type. That could be the cause of the type conversion error.

Answer (score 2):

It's now available. (Quoting from http://erpsoftwareblog.com/cloud/2015/08/with-acumatica-you-can-gather-data-by-specified-date/ )

```
=DateAdd(today(),’d’, 9)
```

- y - A number (nbr) of years will be added to the defined date (dt).
- q - A (nbr) of quarters will be added to the defined date (dt).
- m - A (nbr) of months will be added to the defined date (dt).
- d - A (nbr) of days will be added to the defined date (dt).
- w - A (nbr) of weekdays will be added to the defined date (dt).
- ww - A (nbr) of weeks will be added to the defined date (dt).
- h - A (nbr) of hours will be added to the defined date (dt).
- n - A (nbr) of minutes will be added to the defined date (dt).
- s - A (nbr) of seconds will be added to the defined date (dt).

Here are some samples:

```
DateAdd($DueDate, 'm', -2)
DateAdd(CDate('31/01/1995'), 'm', -2)
DateAdd($DueDate,'y', -2)
DateAdd(Cdate($DueDate), 'd', -2)
```