# Acumatica, creating a generic inquiry with a condition on a field equal to the previous day

Tags: date, acumatica, erp

I have created a simple generic inquiry that shows some data after joining two tables. I am now struggling to implement a condition that should make the result only contain rows where a  date field is equal to yesterday date. 
I am a bit annoyed as Acumatica has created the method `today()` neatly, but not a `yesterday()` or `tomorrow()`.

 Does anyone have a good solution that they care to share?

Help is much appreciated,
Cheers.

P.s 
I have made this very hackish solution that somewhat works, but breaks between change in month or year.
=CStr(Year(Today()))+CStr(Month( Today() ))+CStr( Day(Today())-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution to my problem!
I read that Acumatica is coded C# and.NET which made me think of how adding dates is done there. You utilise the `DateAdd(date, interval, number)` under the time tab to create relative changes to date. 
In this case, the `date` is the time source from where you want to change, `interval` is in which interval/dimension you wanna move, for example, 'd' is for days. You can find more prefixes here: [crosspost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48955082/6013371). Lastly, `number` is how much you want to change in the interval, in my case -1.

TLDR; Use DateAdd(Today(), 'd', -1) to get the previous date in relation to the current date.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write Equals to @Today-1 for Yesterday like below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: That was my intuition as well. However, when I do as you suggest I get "Cannot perform the '-' operation on System.DateTime and System.Int32.". 
Maybe we are using different versions?

Comment: @Johnboll are you putting it as a formula? I am not using formula in this case. Make sure to check the From Schema checkbox

Comment: You are correct! I did not check the "From schema" checkbox before.
Your solution is a good alternative, thank you for your time and answer Samvel.